# Visual Studio clears output file at end of debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am experiencing a weird behaviour from Visual Studio 2013. I've got a C# program which writes to the standard output, let's say

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace CsSandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

In the *Debug* tab of the project's properties I have redirected the output to a file, like this:
[image: command line options]

If I open the file within those 10s when my application is still running, the file **does** contain "Hello world!". However, as soon as the program exits, the file is cleared. This does not happen when I run the program from the command line.

Is there a rationale why Visual Studio does it? Is there a way to bypass this behaviour?

Comment: What happens when you run it from the command line? (I have a sneaking suspicion this may be due to the way VS hosts applications... I think it may be starting a new process immediately after the previous one quits, but waiting for you to actually hit "run" before launching *your* part of it...)

Comment: Try >> output.txt.  It seems like its overwriting itself. Using two greater than symbols will append file.  Will create file if none exists.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hm, that may be right, because actually `CsSandbox > output.txt` fails if I use the same output file as in VS. It says the file is used by a different process and it starts working only if I close VS.

Comment: @JasonHughes Thanks, the content of the file is preserved then :) Of course, the file is appended, whereas I would be more happy with an overwrite, but I can live with that too :)

Comment: You could use a streamwriter instead of the command line args, you could wrap it in a debug constraint if you only want it run during debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is due to the way Visual Studio hosts your application, in order to reduce startup time when debugging.

What happens is that your application (Program.exe) will actually be hosted in another process (Program.vshost.exe), which is started with the same command line arguments. When your application ends, this process is immediately restarted. You should be able to see this within Task Manager - look in the details tab so you can see the PID of the processes, and run your app - you'll see one Program.vshost.exe instance which ends when your app finishes, and another one come up immediately. That's then overwriting your output file.

One fix for this is to give your application a command line argument for the file to write to - and open that file within your `Main` method. You won't get *there* until you start running the app again.

Another option would be to simply stop using the hosting process - in the Debug part of your project properties, at the bottom you should see a checkbox for "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process". Uncheck this and I think your problem will go away - but it'll take longer to start debugging.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtemp/archive/2004/08/17/215764.aspx) for more information about the hosting process.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm adding the argument right now. I will have a look at the blog post later. Good to know such things :)